# Flutter Android programatically close/dismiss ProgressHUD dialog without onPress

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I just new enter and study flutter on Android. I want to ask about the ProgressHUD dialog.

How can I to close/dismiss the ProgressHUD dialog programmatically? Because at the documentation it was using onPress to dismiss the dialog. What I want is to programmatically dismiss or close the dialog without onPress.

Thank you.

**The library/package of the ProgressHUD dialog link below:**

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/progress_hud#-readme-tab-

**The code below is initiate the dialog:**

```
    bool _loading = true;

    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _progressHUD = new ProgressHUD(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
      color: Colors.white,
      containerColor: Colors.blue,
      borderRadius: 5.0,
      text: 'Loading...',
    );

    //If I put in this line, there have an error, 
    //the state is null, the dismiss() function called on null.
    _progressHUD.state.dismiss();

  }
```

You can see if I put the `_progressHUD.state.dismiss();` in function `initState()` There is an error which is the state is null, the dismiss() function called on null reference.

**The code below is use to dismiss dialog:**

```
_progressHUD.state.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dismissing progress in init state when the widget is not fully build. So, state null error is showing. To use it inside init state or when state is not fully set, you can use postframe callback.

```
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          _progressHUD.state.dismiss();
        });
```